# Javascript collapsable menu not visible when appears over Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, menu

I'm doing a Javascript menu with collapsable items, but for some days I've unable to make this appear when appear "over" a Silverlight control. Javascript menu uses DIVs to make this collapsable menu but it does't appear meanwhile a Silverlight control is there.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The standard technique for flash, java and select boxes is to use an iframe shim. That is, place an iframe of the same size as the div under the div. Perhaps it would also work for silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make the Silverlight plugin windowless via a param in the object tag:-

```
<object ...>
  <param name="windowless" value="true"/>
  ...
</object>
```

Make sure your div elements in the menu have a higher zorder than the silverlight plug-in.  These elements should appear over the silverlight plugin.

The main downside is performance, if you have Video media playing in Silverlight this is going to be a problem, otherwise it should be ok.  Other downsides listed here:-

[limitations of windowless mode for silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/11/12/limitations-of-windowless-mode-for-silverlight.aspx)